# Taking vowels from string. Java

Tags: java, string

I'm having trouble with this simple exercise. What I have to do is to take the vowels from the string.

This returns all the vowels in the string, but what I want is that if there are multiple letters of same vowel, just return one.For example, using the string **"aaa eee iii"** should give **"a e i"**.

```
public static void getVowels(char aChar, String aString){
  System.out.print("Your string has the following vowels: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++){
      if ((aString.charAt(i) == 'a') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'e') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'i') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'o') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'u')) {
        aChar = aString.charAt(i);
        System.out.print(aChar + " ");
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: instead of printing them out, create a new String.
if ( !newString.contains(vowelFound)) newString += vowelFound;

Comment: you should use `HashSet<Character>` to discard the duplicates.

Comment: What is the point of the parameter aChar?

Comment: Edwin Torres there is no point in it, I was just testing other chances but I forgot to delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your code as follows:

```
public static void getVowels(char aChar, String aString)
{
System.out.print("Your string has the following vowels: ");
String vowels="";
for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++)
{
    if ((aString.charAt(i) == 'a') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'e') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'i') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'o') || (aString.charAt(i) == 'u')) 
    {
        if(!vowels.contains(String.valueOf(aString.charAt(i))))
        vowels+=aString.charAt(i);
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<vowels.length();i++)
    System.out.print(vowels.charAt(i)+" ");
}
```

**EDIT :**

Alternatively,

```
public static void getVowels(char aChar, String aString){
System.out.print("Your string has the following vowels: ");
char vowels[]={'a','e','e','o','u'};
for (char vowel : vowels)
{
    if(aString.indexOf(vowel)>=0)
    {
        System.out.print(vowel+" ");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend either adding each vowel found to a `HashSet<Character>`, or calling `aString.contains()` with each vowel in turn. You can also use `aString.toLowerCase()` so that you only have to check for lowercase vowels.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing for loop? Just check String.IndexOf() and if that character is present print it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **string where you keep on adding unique vowels** checking before hand whether it exists. The below program will clear your doubt.

```
  public class TestWovel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String vowel = "aaaeeeiiizncnzcxjswdmmnmxcuuooo";

    String uniqueVowels = "";

    for(int i=0;i<vowel.length();i++){
        char vowelFound = vowel.charAt(i);
        if((vowelFound == 'a' || vowelFound == 'e' || vowelFound == 'i' || vowelFound == 'o' || vowelFound == 'u') && (uniqueVowels.indexOf(vowelFound) == -1)){
            uniqueVowels+=vowelFound;
         }
        }

    System.out.println(uniqueVowels);           
       }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an integer array whose indexes are ASCII codes. When you see a vowel, check its count in the array. If the count is 0, print the vowel and increase the count. For example, 'a' would be stored in arr[97]:

```
public static void getVowels(String aString) {
    int[] arr = new int[128];
    char c;
    System.out.print("Your string has the following vowels: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < aString.length(); i++){
        c = aString.charAt(i);
        if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') {
            if (arr[c] == 0) {
                System.out.print(aString.charAt(i) + " ");
                arr[c]++;
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is not how you should do this. You are uselessly creating an array which has 128-5=123 indices wasted. You simply waste memory using this approach.

Comment: You can shorten the array (to 118). I picked 128 for the ASCII codes 0-127. I used the array as an alternative to String searching.